# On the inequality-integer system

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove this inequality, but I do not have a good background in algebra, if you can guide me:

We have:
$$
p_1 + 2p_2 + \ldots +kp_k < q_1 + 2q_2 + \ldots +kq_k+(k+1)q_{k+1}+\ldots+tq_t
$$
and
$$
p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_k = q_1+q_2+\ldots+q_k+\ldots+q_t
$$
and
$$
1 \leq l_1 < l_2 < \ldots < l_k < \ldots < l_t
$$
where

- $p_i \in \mathbb{N^*}$,
- $q_i \in \mathbb{N^*}$,
- $l_i\in \mathbb{N^*}$ for all $i$.

Then I need to prove that:
$$
l_1p_1+l_2p_2+\ldots +l_kp_k < l_1q_1+l_2q_2+\ldots+l_kq_k+\ldots+l_tq_t
$$

If anyone can help me please.

P.S.
Sorry, I forget a detail :

$$
p_1 \geq p_2 \geq ... \geq p_k\\
and\\
q_1 \geq q_2 \geq ... \geq q_t
$$
Best regards

Comment: This is not true for $k=2$ and $t=3$. Take $p_1=1,p_2=98, q_1=q_2=q_3=33,l_1=1, l_2=3, l_3=4.$

Comment: Sorry i forget a detail: $p_1 \geq p_2 \geq ... \geq p_k$ and $q_1 \geq q_2 \geq ... \geq q_t$

Comment: Since you say "I need to prove this inequality", does that mean that you already know that it is true? Is it an exercise? What is the motivation?

Comment: No, it is not an exercise, in my work, this inequalities have direct impact in graph theory, I know that is true experimentally after doing tests on known benchmarks and generated data, then i have a light proof which is not really accepted by a group of mathematicians who review the work. So, I need a clear proof or a guide or an idea that i can use to proove this formula to validate my experimentals with them.

Comment: I assume $\mathbb{N}^*$ means the positive integers.  This looks like a question about integer partitions.

Comment: Yes it is positive integers

Comment: This is not true also, $p_1=p_2=50$, $l_1=1, l_2=3, l_3=4$, $q_1=60, q_2=30, q_3=10$

Comment: @ToniMhax Thanks for your response, the problem like it is posed can be land to a such result, which it pushes to verify it again, i find that i have as conditions: $p_1+2p_2+...+kp_k < q_1+2q_2+...+tq_t$ and $k < t$ and i must prove that $l_1p_1+l_2p2+...+l_kp_k < l_1q_1+l_2q_2+...+l_tq_t$. So it is a strict inequality. Thanks for your help.